# Computing Cosine Similarity in Perl

Tags: perl, similarity, trigonometry

How do I compute the cosine similarity distance of two documents in Perl? A few questions:
1) Are there already modules for computing the cosine similarity distance in CPAN? Or is this task easy enough to code up?
2) When I say documents, I really mean that one "document" is a sentence and the other "document" is just a list of keywords. To be fair, should I tokenize, lowercase and sort all the keywords in each document respectively before computing the cosine similarity distance?

Comment: is this a homework / assignment ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, a quick search for [cosine similarity](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=cosine%20similarity) on CPAN brings up [Text::Document](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aDocument).